# Are Stripe's Checkout Sessions stored "forever"?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Using stripe's API and the Integration Builder, before you go to the checkout page, you can get the `id` of the `Ceckout Sessions` in the `create-checkout-session.php` file. (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object?lang=php)

My plan is to use that session ID later on to get the customer's ID and the subscription's ID.

But does these sessions expires? Meaning after some time, i won't be able retrieve that session? (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve?lang=php).

Ps: I don't think it matters, but i'm using PHP as my backend language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be clear,

- You can retrieve the full details of a [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions) any time using the API : https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve. There is no "expiry" for this.
- You can only access the full data of an [Event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events) e.g. `checkout.session.completed` if it was created within the last 13 months from the Dashboard. Events older than 30 days will only provide a summary view. Events within the last 30 days will be fully visible via the API and Dashboard. ([source](https://support.stripe.com/questions/stripe-event-retention-period))
- A Checkout Session expires 24 hours after they’re created (i.e. the customer cannot access/pay via the Checkout [url](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url)), but you can shorten the expiration time by setting `expires_at` ([source](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/abandoned-carts#adjust-session-expiration)). Note that you can still access the details of the Checkout Session as mentioned in the first point.

Ideally, you should rely on webhooks :

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders
- https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

The `checkout.session.completed` event will contain the [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer) and [subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-subscription).

Comment: That's exactly it. I was worried I wouldn't be able to retrieve the details of a Checkout Session after some time. But if those details are accessible at anytime then thats ok. I'll just check in my DB if the user's ID is empty, and if it is, i'll fetch it retrieving it from the check out session ID. But later i'll look into webhooks!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout sessions aren't stored forever. They live for short period of time and after that they expire. However, if you need the customer and subscription id, you can follow the following steps (same i use in one of my project).

1. Create Checkout Session and once user redirect back to the website after successful checkout, retrieve the session using the session Id
2. Inside the retrieve session response, there is a customer (customerId) and subscriptionId if the payment mode is subscription.
3. [image]
4. Get the customer (customerId) and subscriptionId from the session retrieve api response and store both into database for later use.
5. Further to get the customer information, you can use the customer api and pass the customerId to get the detailed information about that customer.
6. [image]
7. Similarly, you can use the subscription api to retrieve the particular subscription.
8. [image]

Comment: I saw this. But assuming the user doesn't make it to the success page (like if right after his subscription payment is completed he closes the tab, or something prevents him to getting to the success page) would this still works? That's my only concern about this method...

Comment: You should not rely on the success redirect to perform important actions. There is no guarantee that the user will not close the browser before that.

Comment: I've never messed with webhooks but i guess i'll have to, apparently is the only reliable way to do this